# How to retrieve actions from FB using either the SDKs or the Graph Explorer based on unique web app URL

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I have used the graph api to create user defined action objects. These return an ID. I do not currently store the ID against the user in my own database. So the question I have is : how do I retrieve the ID of these actions from FB from the unique action url assigned to each one? e.g a sample creation call which was successful was

```
FB.api("/me/og_shamhh:swot?start_time=2011-12-06T13:58:39Z&place=220799367931215&expires_in=806481&pubquiz=http://shamrockirishbar.com/pubquiz?id=2867");
```

Where

> pubquiz=http://shamrockirishbar.com/pubquiz?id=2867

is the unique url for that action object "in real life". It this url I want to use as the key to find the associated action in FB.

Comment: Just to add someting more : its the ID of the created action I want and not the ID of the PAGE represented by the unique url. Each user can only create one action for each unique object and I need to access them to delete them/modify them at the users request.

Answer (score 0):

if you want the ACTION ID of all Actions made by a user you just call:

https://graph.facebook.com/{USERID}/{NAMESPACE}:{ACTION}